# How to use TraceEvents

Tags: c, windows, kernel, trace

I am trying to figure out how to get TraceEvents working so that I can log information about my driver when it first starts up (which happens when I start my pc up) so I can determine if it's functioning properly.

I first started up Visual Studio and selected the KMDF template. Building the driver fixed most of the errors (since that created the tmh files). However, `TRACE_DRIVER` is still undefined and I am not sure where it's from and I need it for the `TraceEvents` function call.

```
NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG config;
    NTSTATUS status;
    WDFDRIVER driver;
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES attributes;

    // Initialize WPP Tracing
    DebugMessage(" ");
    DebugMessage("Starting KMDF");
    DebugMessage((PCSTR) RegistryPath->Buffer);
    DebugMessage(" ");
    WPP_INIT_TRACING(DriverObject, RegistryPath);

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Entry");

    DebugPrint("Mouse Filter Driver Sample - Driver Framework Edition.\n");
    DebugPrint(("Built %s %s\n", __DATE__, __TIME__));

    WDF_DRIVER_CONFIG_INIT(&config, MouFilter_EvtDeviceAdd);

    // Register a cleanup callback so that we can call WPP_CLEANUP when the framework driver object is deleted during driver unload.
    WDF_OBJECT_ATTRIBUTES_INIT(&attributes);
    attributes.EvtCleanupCallback = KMDFEvtDriverContextCleanup;
    DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadDriver;

    status = WdfDriverCreate(DriverObject, RegistryPath, &attributes, &config, &driver);

    if (!NT_SUCCESS(status)) {
        TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_ERROR, TRACE_DRIVER, "WdfDriverCreate failed %!STATUS!", status);
        WPP_CLEANUP(DriverObject);
        return status;
    }

    TraceEvents(TRACE_LEVEL_INFORMATION, TRACE_DRIVER, "%!FUNC! Exit");

    return status;
}
```

Secondly, where exactly will these events get logged at? Based on this doc on [DRIVER_INITIALIZE callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/wdm/nc-wdm-driver_initialize) I am fairly sure they should be saved in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services` and then inside of my driver's directory. But looking at the directory I only see the default start up info that is normally specified inside of the INF file along with another directory labeled `Paramters` so where exactly will TraceEvents get logged at because as of now I don't see any.

Comment: It's a bit tedious to explain the intricacies of how all of this works. I'd suggest reading [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/wpp-software-tracing) them coming back with more specific questions. In this particular case, the TraceEvents macro and TRACE_DRIVER flag are generated by the WPP preprocessor.

Comment: @Luke alright ill do that but I still need this question so that I can figure out why ``TRACE_DRIVER`` is undefiled since I doubt the docs will explain my random bug.

Comment: It's undefined because either you're not defining it or the WPP preprocessor is not running. Look at the WPP_DEFINE_BIT macros [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/adding-wpp-software-tracing-to-a-windows-driver#step-1-define-the-control-guid-and-trace-flags).